# Problem setting SFDX Dev Hub

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I am having trouble setting the dev hub.

I can do

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d
```

and it reports that is has authorised successfully.

But when I do `sfdx force:org:list`

I get this:

```
=== Orgs
     ALIAS  USERNAME                  ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
───  ─────  ────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────────
(U)         my.user@mydomain.com      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  Connected
```

And when I do `sfdx config:set defaultdevhubusername=my.user@mydomain.com` it reports success, but still there's no (D) in the org list, and the dev hub is not set.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Do you get different behavior if you add `--global` to the `config:set` command? This would set the Dev Hub across all projects.

Answer (score 1):

If your `defaultusername` is the same as your `defaultdevhubusername`, it will show `(U)` instead of `(D)`. Unset your default user name (`sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=`), or change to a different name (e.g. by creating a scratch org), and it should change to `(D)`. Check `sfdx force:config:list` to see if `defaultdevhubusername` is correct; if so, you're configured correctly for creating scratch orgs, packages, and package verions (assuming you have the relevant permissions).

```
$ sfdx force:config:list
=== List Config
Name                   Value   Location
─────────────────────  ──────  ────────
defaultdevhubusername  foxhub  Local
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that the default dev hub username has been set, I can create scratch orgs. However, when I list the orgs, both the dev hub and the new scratch org have (U) next to them, I don't know why.

Comment: @NickJ That is unusual. Maybe a combination of local/global settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try following. Make sure you log off from all orgs before trying the following by using sfdx:auth:logoff:all

To set or change the org that you’re developing against, in the VS Code footer, click the org’s name or the plug icon (). Then, select a different org, or choose SFDX: Set a Default Org to authorize a new org. Or, open the command palette and run SFDX: Authorize an Org or SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org.

To open your default org so that you can test your changes or use declarative tools, click the browser icon () in the footer. Or, open the command palette and run SFDX: Open Default Org.

Link - https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/default-org/

Answer (score -1):

Try the following link. Make sure you log off from all orgs before trying the following by using `sfdx:auth:logoff:all`

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/default-org/

Comment: Can you add some of the relevant details here? Links tend to break over time (Salesforce ones included!) making link-only answers not that useful.